# OpenGL shader storage buffer contains incomplete data

Tags: opengl, visual-c++, shader

After reading [this tutorial](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-8-basic-shading/) on basic lighting, I decided to expand the shader code to handle an arbitrary number of lights. According to my googling results the recommended way to do this is to create a shader storage buffer object (SSBO) and buffer in an array of Lamp structs to represent lights:

```
// all vec3 objects are from glm
struct Lamp {
    vec3 pos;
    float power;
    vec3 color;
    vec3 lightDirectionCameraSpace;
    // this constructor is omitted in the struct definition in the shaders
    Lamp(vec3 a, float b, vec3 c) {
        pos = a;
        power = b;
        color = c;
    }
};

// global variable
vector<Lamp> lights;

Lamp lmp1(vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f), 40.0f, vec3(0.3f, 0.7f, 0.9f));
Lamp lmp2(vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f), 40.0f, vec3(1.0f, 0.7f, 0.7f));
lights.push_back(lmp1);
lights.push_back(lmp2);

GLuint LightID;
glGenBuffers(1, &LightID);
```

Then, every render pass, I buffer the lights into the SSBO defined in the shaders (see below):

```
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, LightID);
glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, sizeof(Lamp)*lights.size(), &(lights[0]), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// using binding 0 for the SSBO
glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, LightID);
```

Relevant vertex shader code:

```
#version 430

...

struct Lamp {
    vec3 pos;
    float power;
    vec3 color;
    vec3 lightDirectionCameraSpace;
};

layout(std430, binding = 0) buffer LightArray {
    Lamp[] lights;
} LightArr;

void main() {

...

    for (int i = 0; i < LightArr.lights.length(); i++) {
        // Vector that goes from the vertex to the light, in camera space. M is ommited because it's identity.
        vec3 LightPosition_cameraspace = ( V * vec4(LightArr.lights[i].pos, 1)).xyz;
        LightArr.lights[i].lightDirectionCameraSpace = LightPosition_cameraspace + EyeDirection_cameraspace;
    }

...
```

Relevant fragment shader code:

```
#version 430 core

...

// Ouput data
out vec3 glcolor;

struct Lamp {
    vec3 pos;
    float power;
    vec3 color;
    vec3 lightDirectionCameraSpace;
};

layout(std430, binding = 0) buffer LightArray {
    Lamp[] lights;
} LightArr;

void main(){

    // Material properties
    vec3 MaterialDiffuseColor = texture2D( myTextureSampler, UV ).rgb;
    vec3 MaterialAmbientColor = vec3(0.1,0.1,0.1) * MaterialDiffuseColor;
    vec3 MaterialSpecularColor = vec3(0.3,0.3,0.3);

    glcolor = vec3(0, 0, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < LightArr.lights.length(); i++) {
        // Distance to the light
        float distance = length( LightArr.lights[i].pos - Position_worldspace );

        // Normal of the computed fragment, in camera space
        vec3 n = normalize( Normal_cameraspace );
        // Direction of the light (from the fragment to the light)
        vec3 l = normalize( LightArr.lights[i].lightDirectionCameraSpace );
        // Cosine of the angle between the normal and the light direction, 
        // clamped above 0
        //  - light is at the vertical of the triangle -> 1
        //  - light is perpendicular to the triangle -> 0
        //  - light is behind the triangle -> 0
        float cosTheta = clamp( dot( n,l ), 0,1 );

        // Eye vector (towards the camera)
        vec3 E = normalize(EyeDirection_cameraspace);
        // Direction in which the triangle reflects the light
        vec3 R = reflect(-l,n);
        // Cosine of the angle between the Eye vector and the Reflect vector,
        // clamped to 0
        //  - Looking into the reflection -> 1
        //  - Looking elsewhere -> < 1
        float cosAlpha = clamp( dot( E,R ), 0,1 );

        glcolor +=
            // Ambient : simulates indirect lighting
            // MaterialAmbientColor +
            // Diffuse : "color" of the object
            MaterialDiffuseColor * LightArr.lights[i].color * LightArr.lights[i].power * cosTheta / (distance*distance) +
            // Specular : reflective highlight, like a mirror
            MaterialSpecularColor * LightArr.lights[i].color * LightArr.lights[i].power * pow(cosAlpha,5) / (distance*distance);
    }

    // compute total light, then add ambient
    // Ambient : simulates indirect lighting
    glcolor = MaterialAmbientColor + glcolor;
}
```

The problem is that when the program runs, it only renders the first light (here it's the blue one) added to the list (but displays it pretty much correctly). I did some debugging and found that `LightArr.lights.length() == 1` no matter how many lights I have. Possibly related to this is some flickering on surfaces that are lit from a wide normal angle that wasn't there when I was only using one light.

EDIT: I managed to fix some of this problem but I have no idea why my solution works. I added unused dummy float variables (`float foo;` and `float bar;`) to my `Lamp` struct (both inside of and outside of the shaders) after `vec3 color;` and `vec3 lightDirectionCameraSpace;`. Now, both lights are displayed, although the flickering is still there when there's no reason it would be. Why does adding garbage variables change how many lights the shader renders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your solution works is the OpenGL struct packing rules. OpenGL expects vec3 to be aligned on a vec4 boundary. Check section 7.6.2, and 7.6.2.2 in particular, of the OpenGL 4.3 spec for details about how OpenGL lays out structures in uniform blocks.